# Calculating number of symbols in the file with expl3

Tags: expl3, external-files

I try to calculate total number of symbols in the text file with `expl3` backend as programming language. My idea is firstly to calculate number of symbols in file line:

```
\ior_get_str:NN \g_file_ior \l_line_tl
\tl_map_inline:Nn \l_line_tl { \int_incr:N \l__sergiokapone_count_int}
```

and then add it to collector `\l_total_int`

```
\int_add:Nn \l_total_int {\l_count_int}
```

I thought that it is possible to jump from file line to line with `\ior_if_eof:NTF \g_file_ior`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
bbb
wwww
rrrrr
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \g_file_ior
\tl_new:N  \l_line_tl
\int_new:N \l_line_count_int
\int_new:N \l_total_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\CharCount}{ m }
{
    \ior_open:Nn \g_file_ior {#1}
    \int_zero:N \l_line_count_int
    \int_zero:N \l_total_int

    \ior_if_eof:NTF \g_file_ior {} % jumping from line to line untill not eof
    {
        \ior_get_str:NN \g_file_ior \l_line_tl % Read line to \l_line_tl
        \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_line_tl { \int_incr:N \l_line_count_int} % count number of symbols in \l_line_tl
        \int_add:Nn \l_total_int {\l_line_count_int} % add current number of symbols to collector  \l_total_int 
    }
\int_use:N \l_total_int


}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CharCount{\jobname.dat}

\end{document}
```

I always get `3` instead right number (`12` in MWE case). Please, help me to understand.

Comment: You're reading just the first line, the test with `_eof` is done exactly once.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer How can I jump to next line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `expl3` code has an experimental feature (well, it's there since 2012) named `ior_map_inline` which reads one line after another one and processes the line with some user-defined macro, here called `\count_number_of_characters:n` which uses the line content as argument.

In this macro, I've used `\tl_count:N` to get the number of characters.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
bbb
wwww
rrrrr
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \g_file_ior
\tl_new:N  \l_line_tl
\int_new:N \l_line_count_int
\int_new:N \l_total_int

\cs_new:Nn \count_number_of_characters:n {%
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \int_add:Nn \l_total_int {\tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CharCount}{ m }
{
  \ior_open:Nn \g_file_ior {#1}
  \int_zero:N \l_line_count_int
  \int_zero:N \l_total_int

  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_file_ior {
    \count_number_of_characters:n{##1}
  }
  \ior_close:N \g_file_ior
  \int_use:N \l_total_int

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CharCount{\jobname.dat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `ior` mappings are moving to stable: likely to be sent to CTAN today or tomorrow!

Comment: You don't need `\count_number_of_characters:n`: `\int_add:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \tl_count:n {##1} }` would do in the second argument to `\ior_str_map_inline:nn`.

Comment: @JosephWright: I had that in mind, but I was apparently confused that the OP used a  line counting. Of course, `\ior_str_map_oinline:nn` will give the full number of characters

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In `interface3` it is written that the argument`\tl_count: n` should be tokens, but not the file name, as in your example.

Comment: @sergiokapone: Huh? `\tl_count:N` effectively gets the current line, note the difference between `#1` and `##1` there!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok! I thought #1 and ##1 is the same. I rewrite code based on comments to: 
`\NewDocumentCommand{\CharCount}{ m }
{
 \ior_open:Nn \g_file_ior {#1}
 \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_file_ior {\int_add:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \tl_count:n {##1}}}
 \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int
 \ior_close:N \g_file_ior
}`